# UICollectionview изменение выделенной ячейки

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

При выделении ячейки в `UICollectionView` задаю ей рамку, однако при выделении следующей ячейки рамка у предыдущей выделенной клетки остается. Каким образом можно обновить все ячейки кроме выделенной?

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      var selectedcell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
      selectedcell!.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
      selectedcell!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
 }
```

В `cellForItemAtIndexPath` задаю клеткам рамку 0, и по идее `self.collectionView.reloadData()` должно помочь, но если использовать его в `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` то выделение пропадает.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Покажите код метода cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Код: http://pastebin.com/BqGCSTBG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше в `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` запоминать индекс нажатой ячейки, а в `cellForItemAtIndexPath` применять Ваше выделение:

```
...
if mySelectedIndex == indexPath {
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
}
...
```

Ну и дальше, соответственно, можно усложнять. К примеру, запоминать предыдущую выделенную ячейку, нажатую и уже обновлять не все с `.reloadData()`, а по индексам.

Comment: Да, именно так в итоге реализовал, спасибо.